# A conditional SELECT/JOIN from a single SQL Server table in a single query?

Tags: sql-server, select, conditional-statements

I'm struggling with the right type of conditional select statement here, even after searching.

I have a table with users. Some are owners, some are just guests, like so:

```
TABLE A 
UserID    | UserType | Directory | RegisteredToID | Name
1         | Guest    |           | 3              | Bob
2         | Guest    |           | 3              | Susan
3         | Owner    | abc       | (null)         | Charles
4         | Guest    |           | 20             | Hugh
etc...
```

I'm trying to get one query statement that results the Bob, Susan, and Charles records with the directory name showing for each, like so:

```
Name    | Directory
Bob     | abc
Susan   | abc
Charles | abc
```

In other words, Bob and Susan are guests of Charles, but Charles' record contains the directory name I want. Hope my question makes sense?

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned this twist....I won't know the directory name, just a userID (e.g. 1 for Bob) and am trying to retrieve the correct directory name to associate for each user, whether they are a guest or not. Only owner records have a directory name filled in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the table on itself and decide with [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) which Directory to select.

Out of my head (don't have access to a SQL Server at the moment):

```
SELECT
    t1.Name,
    CASE WHEN t1.RegisteredToID is null
        THEN t1.Directory 
        ELSE t2.Directory 
    END AS Directory
FROM 
    TableA AS t1
LEFT JOIN TableA AS t2 
    ON t1.RegisteredToID = t2.UserID
```

Comment: +1 This ends up with a null for Hugh's directory, but that's probably just bad sample data because I would assume that there would be a FK Constraint on RegisteredToID

Comment: @ConradFrix: Even if there wouldn't be a FK Constraint and Hugh would be a guest of "no one" - then IMO Null would be correct, because we can't find a directory for Hugh.

Comment: I see your point, I was trying to get across that even though your SQL doesn't match the desired output its probably due to bad sample data

Comment: This is the answer, thank you for the help! If I add a WHERE name = 'xxxx' clause to your example, it's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution with a CTE for data below:

```
With TABLEA as(

SELECT 1 as UserID, 'Guest' as UserType, NULL as Directory, 
       3 as RegisteredToID, 'Bob' as Name
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Guest', NULL, 3, 'Susan'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Owner', 'abc', NULL, 'Charles'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Guest', NULL, 20, 'Hugh'
)


SELECT B.name, A.Directory
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableA B
    ON A.UserID = B.RegisteredToID
    OR A.UserID = b.UserID
WHERE A.Directory = 'abc'
```

Comment: Ah this is very close, except I realize I left out one piece of the puzzle -- I won't know the directory name, just a user's name (e.g. Bob), and want to pull all the user records associated with Bob and INCLUDE the directory name for each one. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is missing the possibility that userID 1 could be an owner on a different entry with a Directory of ijk having a  guest of 2.  in that  situation a duplicate name would be entered.  placing a additional criteria on the OR could eliminate the problem.

Comment: @xQbert - sub-sub users wasn't something included in the OP's scenario

Answer (score 1):

I modified JNK's answer so that it would work with any combination of directory names, not just specific to 'abc'

```
SELECT B.name, A.Directory
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableA B
    ON A.UserID = B.RegisteredToID
    OR A.UserID = b.UserID
WHERE A.Directory <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a different way of doing it...  as pointed out in comments, this doesn't work if a user can be an owner and a guest  I'd just need to understand the data better to tweek it though.

```
Select B.Name, A.Directory 
from Nova A
INNER JOIN Nova B 
  on A.UserID = B.RegisteredtoID or 
   (B.RegisteredtoID is null AND A.userID=B.userID)
  where a.directory is not null
```

This basically says get all the people affiliated with the owner including the owner ignoring situations where the affiliation doesn't have a directory defined.  However if the owner is listed more than once in the table... I would likely have problems with this query.

Comment: This will not return the correct `directory` for sub-members.