# Using a list with a selected item as a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Let us consider the following table structures:

```
Table1

Table1_ID  A
1          A1
2          A1;B1
```

and

```
Table2

Table2_ID  Table1_ID  B       C
1          1          foobar  barfoo 
2          2          foofoo  barbar
```

The view I'm using is defined by the following query:

```
SELECT Table1.A, B, C
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Table1_ID = Table2.Table1_ID;
```

95% of A's data consists in a 2 characters long string. In this case, it works fine. However, 5% of it is actually a list (using a semicolon as a separator) of **possible** values for this field.

This means my users would like to **choose** between these values when it is appropriate, **and** keep using the single value automatically the rest of the time. Of course, this is not possible with a single `INNER JOIN`, since there cannot be a constant selected value.

Table2 is *very* large, while Table1 is quite small. Manually filling a local A field in each row within Table2 would be a **huge** waste of time.

Is there an efficient way for SQL (or, more specifically, SQL Server 2008) to handle this? Such as a list with a selected item within a field?

I was planning to add a "A_ChosenValue" field that would store the chosen value when there's a list in A, and remain empty when A only stores a single value. It would only require users to fill it 5% of the time, which is okay. But I was thinking there could be a better way than using two columns to store a single value.

Comment: Have you considered using XML on your field A? You could easily have an XML list with an attribute "selected" on the selected item.

Comment: Can I make it dynamically load Table1.A's value as the list model? What if Table1.A is modified afterwards? (e.g. it is no longer a list)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would just alter your schema and add a new entity to support the many-to-many relationship between Table1 and Table2 such as the following with a compound key of all three columns.

```
Table3

| Table1_ID | Table2_ID | A  |
-----------------------------
|    1      |     1     | A1 |
------------------------------
|    2      |     2     | A1 |
------------------------------
|    2      |     2     | B1 |
------------------------------
```

You could then do a select and join on this table and due to it being indexed you won't lose any performance.

Without altering the table structure or normalizing data it is possible using a [conditional select statement like that shown in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141184/a-conditional-select-join-from-a-single-sql-server-table-in-a-single-query) but the query wouldn't perform so well as you would have to use a function to split the values containing a semi-colon.

Comment: This is not a many-to-many relationship. It is a 1:n relationship between Table1 and Table2.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I added a LocalA column in Table1, in order that my view actually selects `ISNULL(LocalA, Table1.A)`. Therefore, the displayed value equals A by default, and users can manually overwrite it to select a specific value when A stores a list.

I am not sure whether this is the most efficient solution or not, but at least it works without requiring two columns in the view.